# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode

Tags: hibernate

greetings all, i got this exception in the following method and i don't know why:

```
List<Date> temps = getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "select distinct date(uploadDate) from FileDomain where projectId=:projectId"
                                + " and entityId not in(select fileId from FileVersion) order by date(uploadDate) desc ")
                .setLong("projectId", projectId).list();
```

Comment: Please post your entities and the full exception trace (including the Abstract Syntax Tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the `date()` from `distinct date(uploadDate)` so it is just `select distinct uploadDate from...`

most likely problem is that your dialect does not configure the `date` function, so if it's not required, remove it.